# 404 not found in embedded jetty with multiple WebAppContext

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, web-applications, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded jetty server to deploy my applications.I want to use same jetty instance to deploy 2 different wars on different connectors (one on http and other on https). My code is provided below:

```
private static void startServer() throws Exception
{

    Server= new Server();
    ServerConnector https_connector = null;
    ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server); 
    httpConnector.setPort(18081);
    httpConnector.setName("Http_connector");

    httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server); 

    HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration(); 
    https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer()); 
    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory(); 
 sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(serviceConfig.getSecurityCertificatePath());
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(KEY_STORE_PD);
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(KEY_MANAGER_PD); 
    https_connector = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()), new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
        https_connector.setName("Https_connector");

    if(https_connector != null)
    {
        https_connector.setPort(18080); 
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {https_connector, httpConnector});
    }

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer", "false");
    webapp.setContextPath("/hello1");
    File warFile = new File("../HelloWorld/webapps/hello1.war");
    webapp.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"Https_connector"});
    if(!warFile.exists())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unable to find WAR File: " + warFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    webapp.setWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());

    Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault( server );
    classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration" );

    webapp.setAttribute(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$" );

    webapp.setCopyWebDir(true);
    webapp.setCopyWebInf(true);
    webapp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    webapp.setPersistTempDirectory(false);

    HandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.addHandler(webapp);

    ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler();
    contextHandler.setContextPath("/hello1resources");
    ResourceHandler resourceHandler= new ResourceHandler();
    File resourceBase = new File("../HelloWorld/webapps/hello1resources");
    if(!resourceBase.exists())
    {
        new File("../HelloWorld/webapps/hello1resources").mkdir();
    }
    resourceHandler.setResourceBase(resourceBase.getAbsolutePath());
    resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
    contextHandler.setHandler(resourceHandler);
    contexts.addHandler(contextHandler);

    //************************************
    WebAppContext webapp1 = new WebAppContext();
    webapp1.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer", "false");
    webapp1.setContextPath("/hello2"");
    File warFile1 = new File("../HelloWorld/webapps/hello2.war");
    if(!warFile1.exists())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unable to find WAR File: " + warFile1.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    webapp1.setWar(warFile1.getAbsolutePath());

    webapp1.setAttribute(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$" );

    webapp1.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"Http_connector"});
    webapp1.setCopyWebDir(true);
    webapp1.setCopyWebInf(true);
    webapp1.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    webapp1.setPersistTempDirectory(false);
    contexts.addHandler(webapp1);

    ServletContextHandler contextHandler1 = new ServletContextHandler();
    contextHandler1.setContextPath("/hello2resources");
    ResourceHandler resourceHandler1= new ResourceHandler();
    File resourceBase1 = new File("../HelloWorld/webapps/hello2resources");
    if(!resourceBase1.exists())
    {
        new File(serviceConfig.resourceBase1).mkdir();
    }
    resourceHandler1.setResourceBase(resourceBase1.getAbsolutePath());
    resourceHandler1.setDirectoriesListed(false);
    contextHandler1.setHandler(resourceHandler1);
    contexts.addHandler(contextHandler1);

    //*********************************
    contextHandler = new ContextHandler();
    contextHandler.setContextPath(serviceConfig.getServiceResourceContextPath());
    resourceHandler= new ResourceHandler();
    resourceBase = new File(serviceConfig.getServiceResourceBase());
    if(!resourceBase.exists())
    {
        new File(serviceConfig.getServiceResourceBase()).mkdir();
    }
    resourceHandler.setResourceBase(resourceBase.getAbsolutePath());
    resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
    contextHandler.setHandler(resourceHandler);
    contexts.addHandler(contextHandler);

    server.setHandler(contexts); 
    LOGGER.info("just before starting server...");
    server.start();       
}
```

Code Details:
I have created 2 connectors: http_connector and https_connector
and created two different webAppContext for both the applications webapp  and webapp1. Also assigned virtualhosts to both webAppContexts.
I have kept both the war files in same webapps folder.

Now when server is started I am unable to connect to any of application from browser:
Urls: 
Application1: https://localhost:18080/hello1/
Application1: http://localhost:18081/hello2

In both cases following error is genetrated
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /clearinsight. Reason: Not Found

So far tried solutions which did not work:
I have created two separate webAppContexts for both the applications and single server and only one http connector.

I do not want to launch 2 separate jetty server instances for the applications.

Could anyone please suggest is it possible to deploy 2 webAppContexts inside one jetty server instance in embedded mode?

If yes, what is the problem with provided code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you keeping your resources outside of your webapp? (that's a spec breaking decision).  Since this is an embedded jetty setup, why not just use an exploded webapp with the resources in place?

Comment: I didn't get the part "exploded webapp with the resources in place", could you please give an example of folder hierarchy, since I am new to web application world.

Comment: Exploded webapp is just a war file unpacked into a directory.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks Joakim.